# Writing bash conditionalwith nested piped command

Tags: bash

The following bash command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/dir | grep _SUCCESS | wc -l
```

prints:

> 0

What I want is, when the result is indeed 0, to print FAILURE to the terminal.

This is what I've tried:

```
if [ aws s3 ls s3://bucket/dir | grep _SUCCESS | wc -l = 0]; then echo FAILURE; fi
```

but nothing is printed. it looks like it is waiting for more input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```sh
if [ "$(aws s3 ls s3://bucket/dir | grep _SUCCESS | wc -l)" -eq 0 ]; then echo FAILURE; fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `wc` at all. If the line count is zero, that means `grep` produced no output, in which case it will have a non-zero exit status. The `if` statement only cares about the exit status anyway.

```
if ! aws ls s3://bucket/dir | grep -q _SUCCESS; then
    echo FAILURE
fi
```

The `!` negates the exit status of the pipeline (which is the exist status of the left-most failure, otherwise 0), so that you don't have to write something like

```
if aws ls s3://bucket/dir | grep -q _SUCCESS; then
    :  # Do nothing
else
    echo FAILURE
fi
```

`grep -q` suppresses its output, since you are only interested in the exit status, not the actual output.

---

Strictly speaking, `grep` has an exit status of 1 if there is no match, and a different non-zero value, usually 2, if there is an actually error. If you care, you need to check the value of `$?` explicitly after running the command.

```
aws ls s3://bucket/dir | grep -q _SUCCESS
case $? in
    0) : ;;
    1) echo FAILURE ;;
    *) echo "Some other error" ;;
esac
```